# Alpha overlay not rendering correctly in Eevee Blender, but display correctly in viewport

Tags: blender, viewport, alpha

I have two textures with transparency overlaying on top of each other (the hair, as a multiple alpha overlay) via Material nodes. At first the overlay would not display correctly (one texture would cancel the other out), which I solved following this thread:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86617/how-to-stack-layer-two-textures-with-alpha-over-each-other-with-material-nodes/239331?noredirect=1#comment405876_239331

I solved the problem in the viewport, however when I render the image the alpha textures again display incorrectly, see screenshot:

[Alpha Render Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDjgC.jpg)

Playing with the material settings did not change the rendered result. I'm not sure how to go about solving this - any help is appreciated and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION:

The Solidify Modifier (for correct backface culling) wasn't enabled in the render view, only in viewport ‍♀️

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).